# With google maps api know if there is a customs between 2 places

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In Google map API, how to know if to go from an origin place to a destination place you have to pass customs of Mexico or customs of United States?

Comment: Uhmm if you cross the border ... there's customs. BTW just out of curiosity, what are you smuggling?

Comment: Check the country of origin and country of destination, and if one of them is Mexico and the other is the US, then there is a customs crossing? Unless you're good at climbing walls or swimming across rivers, of course. Digging a tunnel is also another solution, but that will take longer. If that does not work, open your console and check for Cross Origin errors.

Answer (score 0):

This user public map shows the known checkpoints but I don't think google exposes that information in the general gmaps api.

https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1L872WkbWL11Zob-E9Oyk_Zen1Ws&hl=en_US&ll=32.16624724270462%2C-107.19907796875003&z=5